# Magento 2 How add dynamic rows field to custom widget

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, widget, dynamic

I need add dynamic rows field to my custom widget, which should have three columns: title(text field), color(select field), url(text field). There should also be an add button, and delete buttons for each row. If possible, it would be nice to be able to swap lines. I suppose in widget.xml I have to declare a block type and specify a class, but I don’t understand how the code of this class should look.

Comment: did you achieved??

Comment: unfortunately no(

Answer (score 1):

i have used @bbakalov's module from github and it works:
https://github.com/bbakalov/Bss_DynamicRows

Hope it serves you!

Update: i have been ansered to my question, which was to add dynamic rows with block (not Ui Components):
[Add dynamic rows (No UI Component) block, into the custom widget](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/349847/add-dynamic-rows-no-ui-component-block-into-the-custom-widget)