# Add dynamic rows (No UI Component) block, into the custom widget

Tags: magento2, widget, widgets, dynamic-rows

I need to add dynamic rows into the custom-made-widget, without uiComponent.
I have a system.xml with the block:

```
<section id="general" type="text">
   <group id="quantity_ranges" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
       <label>Quantity Ranges</label>
         <field id="ranges" translate="label" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <label>Ranges</label>
                <frontend_model>Vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\DynamicRows</frontend_model>
...
```

and the Block:
Vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\DynamicRows

```
class DynamicRows extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    public function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['label' => __('Sku'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('position', ['label' => __('Position'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
}
```

and it works. BUT, I need this into the widget, which does NOT work:

```
<parameter name="hotspots" xsi:type="block" required="false" visible="true">
  <label translate="true">Hotspots products</label>
  <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Hospot" />
</parameter>
```

> block:
> \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Hospot

```
class Hospot extends Template
{
    public function prepareElementHtml(AbstractElement $element): AbstractElement
    {
        // Create the dynamics rows
        $dynamicRows = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(AbstractFieldArray::class);
        $dynamicRows->addColumn('label', ['label' => __('Sku')]);
        $dynamicRows->addColumn('position', ['label' => __('Position')]);

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $dynamicRows->toHtml() . "<script>require(['mage/adminhtml/browser']);</script>");

        return $element;
    }
}
```

Has anyone had faced this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new *Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Hospot* class you're trying to create a block from an abstract class. This is not possible. Instead, you should use a separate class that is instantiated from the given abstract class. And additionally, you have to set an *$element* for this new class. So here is how your *Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Hospot* class should look like:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Hotspot extends Template
{
    public function prepareElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $dynamicRows = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(
                DynamicRows::class
            )->setElement(
                $element
            );

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $dynamicRows->toHtml() . "<script>require(['mage/adminhtml/browser']);</script>");

        return $element;
    }
}
```

**BUT!** When trying to save the widget you will be getting an error. Because in *Magento\Widget\Model\Widget::getDirectiveParam()* Magento tries to implode the array of the widget settings. And since the dynamic rows value is a multi-level array, it cannot be converted to a string using the *implode()* function. So probably you will need to add a couple of class plugins to convert the value to a string.

Comment: Yesssss! It works!!! It's exactley what i need it. Thanks a lot @MagestyApps

Answer (score 0):

@AcidBurn, could you share the answer to the saving problem? This is an ideal solution to a widget I'm building, but I'm having trouble saving the widget as @MagestryApps already predicted.

Comment: This is not answer to the question. Please add it as a comment to MagestyApps answer

Comment: I have created a custom table and saved the post data (widget data, with a Controller) in the database.
But you can, also, just save the widget data and it will be saved in the Widget instance.